# ServletException error running a Spring project on STS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to run a spring project on spring tool suite an getting this error

```
 SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5506)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        The import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration cannot be resolved
        The method addListener(ContextLoaderListener) is undefined for the type ServletContext
        Dynamic cannot be resolved to a type
        The method addServlet(String, DispatcherServlet) is undefined for the type ServletContext

        at com.sprhib.init.Initializer.<init>(Initializer.java:5)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:144)
        ... 8 more
```

Here is the code from pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>spr-mvc-hib-master</name>
  <properties>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.6</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.15</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
          <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/Users/muhammadatif/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/Users/muhammadatif/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target</directory>
    <finalName>app-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
          </additionalProjectnatures>
          <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
          </additionalBuildcommands>
          <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
          <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
              <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
              <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
              <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
          <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/Users/Downloads/spr-mvc-hib-master/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe try to post your code

Comment: i posted the code from pom.xml

Comment: Unresolved compilation problems: The import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration cannot be resolved

Comment: So you get an error, but what is your question?

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problem" is what you get when you try to run code with compilation errors. The eclipse Java compiler tries its best to generate bytecode even if your code has compilation errors in it, but when you actually hit the bits of code that don't compile you will get that error. So double-check if you see any error markers on your code (red X markers) or in the eclipse problems view. Find out what exactly the error is and try to resolved it before running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServletRegistration is a Servlet 3.0 class - but you specify servlet-api 2.5 in your pom.

You'll also need tomcat 7 or 8 at least.